# Vertical align html input text on Blackberry

Tags: html, css, blackberry, text, input

Anyone knows how to center text in a input type text on blackberry devices?

That's my CSS:

```css
.input_text {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 305px;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

It works on every browser/device except for the Blackberry.

Comment: Vertical align is a bit of a bugger. It does not work as expected on most elements. Is your text box a multi-line box, or is it a single line?

Comment: What is the text doing currently on the BB? Is it aligning to the bottom? If so adding padding to the input field equal to the space at the top could possibly solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a huge `line-height` and `vertical-align: middle` you could use a padding:

```
.input_text {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 305px;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 12px 0; /***  12px = (38px - 14px) / 2  ***/ 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```